# An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host in WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, exception

I have an abstract class called 'Template' defined as:

```
[DataContract]
public abstract class Template
{
    [DataMember]
    public virtual int? Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual byte[] TemplateDoc { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual bool IsSystemTemplate { get; set; }        
}
```

Two derived classes: UserTemplate and SystemTemplate implements above abstract class, which are defined as:

```
public class UserTemplate : Template
{
    [DataMember]
    public virtual Int32? OfficeId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual Int32? UserId { get; set; }

    protected UserTemplate() { }

    public UserTemplate(string title, byte[] templateDoc, string templateDocName, TemplateType templateType, int officeId, int? userId)
    {
        this.Title = title;
        this.TemplateDoc = templateDoc;
        this.IsSystemTemplate = false;
        this.OfficeId = officeId;
        this.UserId = userId;
    }
}

public class SystemTemplate : Template
{
    [DataMember]
    public virtual Int32? MultiListGroupId { get; set; }

    protected SystemTemplate() { }

    public SystemTemplate(string title, byte[] templateDoc, string templateDocName, TemplateType templateType, int multiListGroupId)
    {
        this.Title = title;
        this.TemplateDoc = templateDoc;
        this.IsSystemTemplate = true;
        this.MultiListGroupId = multiListGroupId;
    }
}
```

Now, when I try to call following service method:

```
List<Template> GetTemplatesByTemplateType(int officeId, int? userId, TemplateType templateType)
```

I get this error:

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Is it because of the reason that I am trying to return an abstract class?
It runs fine if I try to call this method using unit test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the problem is your abstract base class which needs to be decorated with the KnownType and XmlInclude attributes. See here: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200221095858/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/ugandadotnet/archive/2008/05/27/serializing-an-abstract-data-contract.aspx)

Comment: Dead link, but this other S/O question gives the same solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3101756/using-wcf-with-abstract-classes

Answer (score 3):

In addition to grenade's answer about making those descendant classes known to WCF usign the `KnownType` (or `ServiceKnownType`) attribute, you'll also have to decorate the descendant classes with a `[DataContract]` attribute themselves.

```
[DataContract]
public class UserTemplate : Template
{
    ......
}

[DataContract]
public class SystemTemplate : Template
{
    ......
}
```

These attributes are almost never inherited from parent to child in WCF - you need to be very explicit and clear about your intent at every level.

Check this blog post [All About KnownTypes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sowmy/all-about-knowntypes) for more information on the KnownTypes and ServiceKnownTypes attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Add this datacontractserializer line in your web config file

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior >
        **<dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646"/>**
     </behavior >
 </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error once, and it was quite confusing. My problem was that the Service Reference was for some reason not up to date, so updating the Service Reference helped.