# WCF: How to use an abstract class as DataContract

Tags: c#, wcf

I want to use an abstract class to define it as DataContract for WCF. The following example shows how I define my abstract class `UpperClass`.

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
[KnownType(typeof(SubClass1))]
[KnownType(typeof(SubClass2))]
abstract public class UpperClass
{
    abstract public void update();
}
```

`SubClass1` and `SubClass2` inherit from `UpperClass`. Actually, they only share 1 method named `update()`, which is only used internally (not a DataMember). The following code shows the implementation of `SubClass1` and `SubClass2`:

```
[DataContract]
public class SubClass1 : UpperClass
{
    private int[] _val1;
    private int[] _val2;

    //internal constructor:
    public SubClass1()
    {
        _val1 = new int[2];
        _val2 = new int[2];

        //initialize values of _val1 and _val2 ...
    }

    //internal update method
    public override void update()
    {
        //here comes update formulas...
    }

    //enable simple access from WCF client:
    [DataMember]
    public int[] val1
    {
        get { return _val1; }
        set { _val1 = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public int[] val2
    {
        get { return _val2; }
        set { _val2 = value; }
    }
}





[DataContract]
public class SubClass2 : UpperClass
{
    private int[] _value1;
    private int[] _value2;

    //internal constructor:
    public SubClass2()
    {
        _value1 = new int[12];
        _value2 = new int[12];
    }

    // ...
```

On the server side, I supply my survice using the following code, which is defined as [OperationContract(IsInitiating = true, IsTerminating = false)] in its Interface-class.

```
public UpperClass init(string s)
{
    if (s.Equals("SubClass1"))
        obj = new SubClass1();
    else if (s.Equals("SubClass2"))
        obj = new SubClass2();

    return obj;
}
```

And on the client side, I consume (or initialize) my service using:

```
UpperClass DatSet = proxy.init("SubClass1");
```

When I debug to the end of this line, the content of `DatSet` looks very strange:

> {MyExternalLayer.IMyProcessingLayer_proxy.SubClass1}
>       [MyExternalLayer.IMyProcessingLayer_proxy.SubClass1]: {MyExternalLayer.IMyProcessingLayer_proxy.SubClass1}
>       ExtensionData: {System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject}
>       extensionDataField: {System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject}
>       PropertyChanged: null

Comment: What does the exception message say?

Comment: Somehow I got rid of the exception. Sorry, but I don't know why. However, my variable `DatSet` has very weird content. It seems like deserialization to `SubClass1` does not work as I expect it to.

Comment: It looks quite normal to me. Maybe you could explain what you expect?

Comment: I want `DatSet` to be an object of type `SubClass1`, which has two variables: `val1` and `val2`. Instead, it seems to be of type `UpperClass`, which does not have the two variables `val1` and `val2`. But when I write `SubClass1 DatSet = proxy.init("SubClass1");` I get a type conversion exception. How can my client consume those two variables `val1` and `val2`?

Comment: But that's the point of putting it into a UpperClass reference, no? I think your confusion stems from the OOP concept and has nothing to do with WCF. Try the same without the proxy just instantiating the classes directly, I think you will have the same problems.

Comment: that is very likely, yes ;-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using WCF with abstract classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3101756/using-wcf-with-abstract-classes)

Answer (score 0):

I pasted your Data Contracts into a WCF service and they work just fine, although I do not recommend having business logic (abstract public void update();) in your data contracts and transcending service boundaries. But that's just an opinion.