# How to return IEnumerable in WCF ? An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: c#, wcf

I tried return a IEnumerable in WCF service

IService1.cs

```
[OperationContract] 
IEnumerable GetAllTasks(string PersonName);
```

Service1.cs

```
MyEntities db=new MyEntities ();
private IEnumerable getAllTask;

public IEnumerable GetAllTasks(string PersonName)
{
      getAllTask= db.GetAllTaskOfPerson(PersonName).ToList();
      return getAllTask;
}
```

Client

```
Service.ServiceClient ws=new Service.ServiceClient().ToList();
grid.DataSource=ws.GetAllTasks("John");
grid.DataBind();
```

I get this error  :

> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Comment: possible duplicate of [An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host in WCF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087680/an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host-in-wcf)

Comment: I could not solve by this link.

Comment: Turn on tracing for better information http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271517/how-to-turn-on-wcf-tracing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try making your IEnumerable a strongly typed collection. Wcf behaves well when using a `Collection<T>` or `List<T>` in the signature of an operationcontract

Comment: This S/O article is an alternative to generics/typed enums https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3101756/using-wcf-with-abstract-classes