# c# Webservices Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf

I have a c# web application that calls an API, It was working fine until past two weeks since then it started failing with below error.

> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing
>   connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

When I try the same code with c# console application, it is working fine without any errors.

Can anyone please let me know why am I getting the error?

Comment: Does your web api communicate using SSL or TLS? Is there a chance that the security protocol was upgraded?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087680/an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host-in-wcf

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be fixed if you increase the corespond binding attribute elements both on client and server sides. I looked into the issue and it seems to be the most relevant suggestion to fix this.

Here are some good forums where this problem is discussed in more detail.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7b43e645-02f7-4cec-b669-55867c9bb56c/systemnetsocketssocketexception-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host?forum=wcf

https://forums.asp.net/t/1517757.aspx?WCF+issues+sending+large+data+An+existing+connection+was+forcibly+closed+by+the+remote+host+